# boostrap 2.3.2 carousel internet explorer images back to original size on transition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have implemented a slideshow with bootstrap carousel. It works fine in Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer.

When the images are sliding out of view, the image appears as the original size for a second. Of course, when the browser window is sized very narrow, this becomes very disruptive.

You can take a look here: http://websonalized.com/citec/

For the carousel, I have html code:

```
<div id="frontpagecarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/computer-lab.png" alt="Informática Administrativa" title="Informática Administrativa" />
            <div class="module dark large hidden-phone">
                <div class="heading">
                    Informática Administrativa
                </div>
                <div class="bodytext">
                    Aprende los programas y aplicaciones más usuales en actividades administrativas y educativas
                </div>
                <a class="btn" href="#">
                    Más Información
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-inverse btn-large visible-medium" href="#">
                Cursos de Informática Administrativa 
                <span class="block">Más Información</span>
            </a> 
            <a class="btn btn-inverse btn-large visible-small" href="#">
                Informática Administrativa
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/curso-prepa-abierta.png" alt="Preparatoria Abierta" title="Preparatoria Abierta" />
            <div class="module dark large hidden-phone">
                <div class="heading">
                    Preparatoria Abierta
                </div>
                <div class="bodytext">
                    Termina tu bachillerato en 3 semestres o menos, y recibe tu certificado expedido por las SEP
                </div>
                <a class="btn" href="#">
                    Más Información
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-large visible-medium" href="#">
                Clases Reales de Preparatoria Abierta 
                <span class="block">Más Información</span>
            </a> 
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-large visible-small" href="#">
                Preparatoria Abierta
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/informatica-contable.png" alt="Informática Contable" title="Informática Contable" />
            <div class="module dark large hidden-phone">
                <div class="heading">
                    Informática Contable
                </div>
                <div class="bodytext">
                    Destaca en funciones contables y fiscales: nomina, SUA, polizas, activo-pasivo-capital, impuestos, etc.
                </div>
                <a class="btn" href="#">
                    Más Información
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-large visible-medium" href="#">
                Cursos de Informática Contable 
                <span class="block">Más Información</span></a> 
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-large visible-small" href="#">
                    Informática Contable
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/diseno-publicitario.png" alt="" />
            <div class="module dark large hidden-phone">
                <div class="heading">
                    Diseño Publicitario
                </div>
                <div class="bodytext">
                    Nosotros te ayudamos a darle vuelo a tu imaginación y te ensenamos a crear volantes, tarjetas de presentación, invitaciones, calendarios, y más
                </div>
                <a class="btn" href="#">
                    Más Información
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-large visible-medium" href="#">
                Aprende Diseño Publicitario 
                <span class="block">Más Información</span>
            </a> 
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-large visible-small" href="#">
                Diseño Publicitario
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/ingles-conversar.png" alt="Inglés Conversacional" title="Inglés Conversacional" />
            <div class="module dark large hidden-phone">
                <div class="heading">
                    Inglés Conversacional
                </div>
                <div class="bodytext">
                    Aprende inglés en 3 cuatrimestres con nuestro nuevo método que es fácil y efectivo
                </div>
                <a class="btn" href="#">
                    Más Información
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large visible-medium" href="#">
                Curso Inovador y Efectivo de Inglés Conversacional <span class="block">Más Información</span>
            </a> 
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large visible-small" href="#">
                Inglés Conversacional
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <a id="leftarrow" class="carousel-control left" href="#frontpagecarousel" data-slide="prev">
        ‹
    </a> 
    <a id="rightarrow" class="carousel-control right" href="#frontpagecarousel" data-slide="next">
        ›
    </a>
</p>
```

To initialize the carousel, javascript:

```
$('#frontpagecarousel').carousel({ interval: 4000, cycle: true });
```

The only styling applied to the container of the carousel

```
.showcase {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  max-height: 532px;
}
.showcase div.module.dark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 13%;
  float: left;
  border: solid 3px #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #414140;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 54px rgba(33, 33, 32, 0.93);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 54px rgba(33, 33, 32, 0.93);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 54px rgba(33, 33, 32, 0.93);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

Could anybody help me figure out how to fix the internet explorer disruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution offered by Henri prompted to figure out the problem, and finally I found a solution

css

```
.carousel.slide, .carousel.slide > div { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. Works fine in Chrome, but not in IE10.

During the transition, the slide items change from this:

```
<div class="item active">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="item active left">...</div>
<div class="item next left">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

The corresponding bootstrap.css is as follows:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
display: block;
line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-inner > .active, .carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left, .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
    left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Setting "position: absolute; ... width: 100%" is causing the problem in IE. While the .next class is assigned to the item, the image renders at it's full height and width (100%). After the transition and the .next class is removed, the image returns to it's relative positioning and scaled values.

I've found a way to override the behavior, but it's not perfect. I still see the behavior on the first transition, but then it's OK after that.

On the slide event, I set the .next .item's width to be the same as .active and on the slid event, I set the now .active .item back to 100%.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    }).on('slide', function (event) {
        $(event.relatedTarget).width($(this).find('.active').width());
    }).on('slid', function (event) {
        $(this).find('.active').width('100%');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. Works fine in Chrome, but not in IE10.

During the transition, the slide items change from this:

```
<div class="item active">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="item active left">...</div>
<div class="item next left">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

The corresponding bootstrap.css is as follows:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
display: block;
line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-inner > .active, .carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left, .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
    left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Setting "position: absolute; ... width: 100%" is causing the problem in IE. While the .next class is assigned to the item, the image renders at it's full height and width (100%). After the transition and the .next class is removed, the image returns to it's relative positioning and scaled values.

I've found a way to override the behavior, but it's not perfect. I still see the behavior on the first transition, but then it's OK after that.

On the slide event, I set the .next .item's width to be the same as .active and on the slid event, I set the now .active .item back to 100%.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    }).on('slide', function (event) {
        $(event.relatedTarget).width($(this).find('.active').width());
    }).on('slid', function (event) {
        $(this).find('.active').width('100%');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, but I am sorry; your response is not a solution; one because you get the error at the get go, even if only once; and second, b/c by making a css adjustment, we can fix the problem. Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in IE11, however the fix proposed as solution didn't work for me. But adding width: 100% to this classes did the trick for me.

```
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this will help anyone.